# Greater than conditional in react not working

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

there might be just something really silly going on here but for some reason an obvious conditional is not becoming true here:

```
const [mouseDown, setmouseDown] = useState(false)
    const [isMouseDownSuccess, setisMouseDownSuccess] = useState(false)
    const delay = 1000;
    const [startPress, setstartPress] = useState(null)

    function handleMouseDown(){
        setstartPress(Date.now())
        setmouseDown(true)
        // console.log(startPress)
    }

    function handleMouseUp(){
        const diff = Date.now - startPress;
        //This if statement for some reason never becomes true.
        if(diff > delay){
            // setisMouseDownSuccess(!isMouseDownSuccess)
            console.log('Long Press')
        }
        // console.log(Date.now())
        setmouseDown(false)
        console.log("difference: " + (Date.now() - startPress)) 
        console.log("delay: " + delay)
        console.log(diff > delay) 
        //This clearly shows a numerical difference^^^....so the if statement should be true.
    }
```

Comment: `const diff = Date.now - startPress;` should be `const diff = Date.now() - startPress;`

Comment: `Date.now() - startPress`. You want this?

Comment: you missed ```()``` in your ```Date.now - startPress```

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wonder

```
diff > delay
```

never becomes true. Simply look what values these 2 variables will have. Delay is set to `1000`.

While diff is set to

```
const diff = Date.now - startPress;
```

While `startPress` is correctly calculated with `Date.now()`, this line forgot the call of the Date.now function with the `()`. `Date.now` gets evaluated to `undefined`, and minus some number is `NaN` aka not a number.

So `diff` holds the value of `NaN` and `NaN` is surprisingly not greater nor smaller nor equal to any number.

Just change it to

```
const diff = Date.now() - startPress;
```